# How do I modify the code in this extension to run the export function via cron after each order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, cron, export, ce-1.9.2.2

I am currently using the Bulk Import+Export Orders to CSV extension that is available at:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-import-export-orders-to-csv.html

The main function that I need is the export orders function, which is working fine. As this lets me import my magento orders into the order processing system which is being used for shipping out the products.

What I am trying to achieve is having the export function run automatically, preferably after every order is received. If not at least at certain times of the day.

I have looked around can't seem to find the information on what i need to look for to modify this to allow the cron functionality. The csv file that is generated is perfect for my processing system, order extensions do not format the files as i need.

I'm not the most experience, but am learning as I go along. Please can someone point me to where i need to look to allow the export function to available via a cron job.

All the advice is appreciated, the website is running on magento 1.9.2.2.

Comment: You need to find the php file that is doing the execution. For example if it is executing by hitting a button(event) than you would have write a script to running the same event and run the cron for that script. I'm not familiar with this exact program but at the end of the day this what your trying to do. If you need help with the script please post more info. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Ffuenf_OrderExporter](https://github.com/ffuenf/Ffuenf_OrderExporter/tree/dev) which I just forked from this very extension. I'll make a bit of a code cleanup there and added directions in [Ffuenf_OrderExporter_Model_Cron](https://github.com/ffuenf/Ffuenf_OrderExporter/blob/dev/app/code/community/Ffuenf/OrderExporter/Model/Cron.php) how you might implement cron functionality. Also remember the settings in [config.xml](https://github.com/ffuenf/Ffuenf_OrderExporter/blob/dev/app/code/community/Ffuenf/OrderExporter/etc/config.xml) which wires the Model to the Magento Cron System.